# JPA is not accepting @table(name = "table")

Tags: mysql, hibernate, jpa

```
package com.pearson.feedback.domain;


import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "CoachMark")
public class CoachMark {

    @Id
    private long coachMarkId;

    public long getCoachMarkId() {
        return coachMarkId;
    }

    public void setCoachMarkId(long coachMarkId) {
        this.coachMarkId = coachMarkId;
    }
}
```

This is giving me an error of: Table 'Feedback.coach_mark' doesn't exist

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'Feedback.coach_mark' doesn't exist
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_72]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_72]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[na:1.8.0_72]
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) ~[na:1.8.0_72]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:404) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.38.jar:5.1.38]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:387) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.38.jar:5.1.38]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:939) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.38.jar:5.1.38]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3878) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.38.jar:5.1.38]
```

I can't figure out why it is not using my table name. How would you proceed?

Comment: Have you tried dropping your schema and allowing hibernate to re-create the tables?  There is nothing wrong with this code.

Comment: I don't have a specific answer, but can suggest that Hibernate seems to be using the table naming strategy ImprovedNamingStrategy: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/javadocs/org/hibernate/cfg/ImprovedNamingStrategy.html.  Do you have any hibernate specific naming strategy parameters in your persistence configuration?

Comment: Looks like JPA is not configured properly. It just skips the JPA @Table and  uses table name based on hibernate default_schema and class name

Answer (score 0):

Just add hibernate-jpa-2.0.jar, and try again. it may be due to JPA configuration issue.
Then please make sure that the Table name is spelled correctly, since MySQL is using *[case sensitive](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/FISHKB/Table+'xxx'+doesn't+exist+error+with+MySQL+server)*  table names comparison setting for lower_case_table_names (probably the value '0').

Answer (score 0):

This may be a one of many possible reasons:

just check your `hibernate.cfg.xml` for `hbm2ddl.auto` property

if it is

```
<property name="hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>
```

then change it to

```
<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>
```

*N.B.: property can be either `create` or `update`*

Comment: FWIW if using JPA nobody in their right mind should be using "hibernate.cfg.xml"

Comment: I agree. But the question was tagged with `hibernate` so I thought that if it's hibernate then this might be the issue coz I've faced it in past :)

Comment: if that is the issue then they should put that in _persistence.xml_ and NOT throw away vendor independence!